# PG_WAL is very big size

Tags: postgresql, diskspace, wal

I have a Postgres cluster with 3 nodes: ETCD+Patroni+Postgres13.

Now there was a problem of constantly growing `pg_wal` folder. It now contains 5127 files. After searching the internet, I found an article advising you to pay attention to the following database parameters (their meaning at the time of the case is this):

```
archive_mode off;
wal_level replica;
max_wal_size 1G;

SELECT * FROM pg_replication_slots;


postgres=# SELECT * FROM pg_replication_slots;
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------+------------
slot_name           | db2
plugin              |
slot_type           | physical
datoid              |
database            |
temporary           | f
active              | t
active_pid          | 2247228
xmin                |
catalog_xmin        |
restart_lsn         | 2D/D0ADC308
confirmed_flush_lsn |
wal_status          | reserved
safe_wal_size       |
-[ RECORD 2 ]-------+------------
slot_name           | db1
plugin              |
slot_type           | physical
datoid              |
database            |
temporary           | f
active              | t
active_pid          | 2247227
xmin                |
catalog_xmin        |
restart_lsn         | 2D/D0ADC308
confirmed_flush_lsn |
wal_status          | reserved
safe_wal_size       |
```

All other functionality of the Patroni cluster works (switchover, reinit, replication);

```
root@srvdb3:~# patronictl -c /etc/patroni/patroni.yml list
+ Cluster: mobile (7173650272103321745) --+----+-----------+
| Member | Host       | Role    | State   | TL | Lag in MB |
+--------+------------+---------+---------+----+-----------+
| db1    | 10.01.1.01 | Replica | running | 17 |         0 |
| db2    | 10.01.1.02 | Replica | running | 17 |         0 |
| db3    | 10.01.1.03 | Leader  | running | 17 |           |
+--------+------------+---------+---------+----+-----------+
```

Patroni patroni-edit:

```
loop_wait: 10
maximum_lag_on_failover: 1048576
postgresql:
  parameters:
    checkpoint_timeout: 30
    hot_standby: 'on'
    max_connections: '1100'
    max_replication_slots: 5
    max_wal_senders: 5
    shared_buffers: 2048MB
    wal_keep_segments: 5120
    wal_level: replica
  use_pg_rewind: true
  use_slots: true
retry_timeout: 10
ttl: 100
```

Help please, what could be the matter?

This is what I see in `pg_stat_archiver`:

```
postgres=# select * from pg_stat_archiver;
-[ RECORD 1 ]------+------------------------------
archived_count     | 0
last_archived_wal  |
last_archived_time |
failed_count       | 0
last_failed_wal    |
last_failed_time   |
stats_reset        | 2023-01-06 10:21:45.615312+00
```

Comment: Could you please share your question in plain text instead of an image somewhere else?

Comment: Fixed and add patroni config

Comment: If `pg_wal` contains around 5120 files, you have to blame `wal_keep_segments`. Otherwise, look at `pg_stat_archiver`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, pg_wal file count is 5127,  pg_stat_archiver added in main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `wal_keep_segments` set to 5120, it is completely normal if you have 5127 WAL segments in `pg_wal`, because PostgreSQL will always retain at least 5120 old WAL segments. If that is too many for you, reduce the parameter. If you are using replication slots, the only disadvantage is that you might only be able to `pg_rewind` soon after a failover.

Answer (score 0):

Hi for anyone landing here figureing out why their (zalando) database cluster is running out of space which is using patroni.

executing `du -h -d 4` on the master database node showed me that
the wal folder got realy large   `./pgdata/pgroot/data/pg_wal`. The reason for that is because replication nodes where not longer healthy and catching up.

I solved it by executing on a node:  `patronictl reinit`   and selecting the unhealty replicas.  You can see the status of replicas with `patronictl list`.  When the nodes where healty again my wal folder size when from 144GB to near zero on the database nodes.